# How to install VMware View Client?

Tags: software-installation, vmware-view

I have tried installing it through the software-center; installed, removed and reinstalled and it is still giving me problems, it simply crashes when I open it. So I tried synaptic, which looks good, so far.

However, when I follow [this documentation](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/340803), it tells me that VMware-view-open-client is old and I want VMware-view-client. I do not see it when I search for it though. I do see the open one.

All my Google searches have not given me exactly what I am looking for. I feel like I'm close, if anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: vmware client, its just the end point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## On ubuntu 14.04:

1. Open software-sources by typing "software and updates" on the dash and open the application.
2. On the "Other Software" tab, make sure that "Canonical partners" has a check mark besides it.

   [image: screenshot for software and updates other software canonical vmware view client]
3. Now, add i386 architecture to dpkg by first opening a terminal (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing terminal or pressing together <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and then typing the following:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```

   and then enter your administrative password.
4. Now, update your software package list by typing:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. And then install vmware-view-client from the same terminal by typing:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vmware-view-client
   ```

   Or you should be able to install it from the software center by typing "vmware view client" in the search bar:

   [image: ubuntu software center vmware view client]

## On ubuntu 12.04:

Enable "Canonical partners" as said in the section for ubuntu 14.04, update using `sudo apt-get update` and then you should be able to install it from the software center or from the terminal (you can skip the `sudo dpkg --add-architecuture i386` part).

---

[(Source)](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2379366)

Comment: Can we have an update for 15.10, please?

Answer (score 3):

I have Lubuntu 15.10 and this is how I manage to get VMware horizon view

Download [VMware](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_horizon_clients/3_0).

Launch Terminal and type:

```
sudo bash [downloaded binary file]
```

The package will be extracted and installed then A GUI Installer will launch to finish the installation.

To launch run command

```
vmware-view
```

Comment: confirmed - this works for ubuntu 14.04/14.10 & ubuntu studio 14.04/14.10 - I installed the vmware-view-client as noted above by i08in however it did not install the VMware Horizon Client which is what i was after. So after:

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vmware-view-client

I ran through @RTan / Jens Erat steps as noted above and was able to get  the VMware Horizon Client up and running and have a launcher in the start menu. thanks again guys!!

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux Mint 18.1 Serena (~Ubuntu 16.04)**

1. [Download vmware horizon client 4 for linux](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_horizon_clients/4_0)
2. Install: `sudo bash DOWNLOADED_FILE`
3. Find *libudev* and set symlink:

   ```
   sudo find /lib/ -type f | grep libudev
   sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
   ```
4. Run programm from start menu or: `vmware-view`

*(Thanks to above posted answers and [linuxmintusers.de](https://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=41214.30))*

Answer (score 0):

to add on the accepted response - if using terminal, to add canonical partners you need following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
```

(as per https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2064014)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner using or configuring linux
but this works well for me even customizing an iso

On Lubuntu

```
sudo apt install g++ libxml2-dev libboost-dev qt5-default qtbase5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5websockets5-dev git cmake libportmidi0 libasound2 python
```

Download `VMware-Horizon-Client-*.x86.bundle` from vmware page *https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_horizon_clients/4_0*.

Then you can run it from the folder it's downloaded `./VMware-Horizon-Client-*.x86.bundle` or `sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-*.x86.bundle`

Create `vmware.sh`

```
echo "vmware-view -q --nonInteractive --fullscreen --nomenubar --lockServer -s your_view_server_FQDN.local" > /.vmware.sh
```

Create `others.sh`

```
#this line will void checking for the view sever certificate if no needed don't use it.
echo "echo "view.sslVerificationMode = \"3\"" > /etc/vmware/view-mandatory-config

#this other line adds your view server FQDN to local hosts file you can repeat it if necessary
echo "192.168.1.1 viewservershortname viewserverFQDN.local" >> /etc/hosts"
#this line cleanses the script after it run once, 
echo "" > /.others.sh
```

Now you can make those scripts run, I preferred to make them run automatically. The way I did it is

```
crontab -e
```

there you can write

```
@reboot /.others.sh
```

save and quit

Edit the file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`
write this command to autostart the view client automatically

```
@vmware-view -q --nonInteractive --fullscreen --nomenubar --lockServer -s your_view_server_FQDN.local
```

Now you can customize your own ubuntu linux vmware view client

P.D. I've used CUBIC to customize the ISO

I've test UCK but didn't work recommend cubic

Answer (score 0):

This is how i installed 64 bit version on 16.04:

1) Download client from from https://www.vmware.com/go/viewclients

2) Uninstall any previous version (if any).

3)

- a) Open a Terminal window.
- b) Change directories to the directory that contains the installer file (xxx.bundle).

4) Run the installer with the following command:

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-x.x.x-yyyyyyy.arch.bundle
```

*or in my case:

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Horizon-Client-4.7.0-7395152.x64.bundle
```

(To note: the "sh" is there to "force" the bundle to be executable.. depending on the permissions YOU have set forth this will also work:

```
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-x.x.x-yyyyyyy.arch.bundle
```

5) Follow the Gui install wizard..